# cometd via websocket: "unknown bayeux transport"

Tags: java, maven, websocket, cometd, bayeux

Im trying to connect to a commetd server via websocket client. I used exactly the code from an [official cometd demo on github](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/blob/master/cometd-demo/src/test/java/org/cometd/demo/Demo.java) without modifications and try to  connect to http://localhost:8080/cometd/test

.. but as soon as my client tries to do the websocket upgrade http request I get a response with "HTTP/1.1 400 Unknown Bayeux Transport"
Any ideas?

I tried it with SSL and without it, the latter obviosly to reduce potential error sources. In both cases I get the same error.

Here is my pom, in case I forgot some important websocket related dependencies

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>de.verlinkied</groupId>
    <artifactId>bayeux-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>


    <properties>
        <jetty.version>9.2.22.v20170606</jetty.version>
        <cometd.version>3.1.3</cometd.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-jmx</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax-websocket-server-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.cometd.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>cometd-java-server</artifactId>
            <version>${cometd.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>de.verlinked.BayeuxServerTest</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

mvn dependency:tree yields the following

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building bayeux-server 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ bayeux-server ---
[INFO] de.verlinkied:bayeux-server:jar:1.0
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-api:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jmx:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-annotations:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-plus:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-jndi:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-xml:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.ow2.asm:asm-commons:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm-tree:jar:5.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-client:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-server:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-servlet:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] |  \- javax.websocket:javax.websocket-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-server:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.cometd.java:bayeux-api:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.cometd.java:cometd-java-common:jar:3.1.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util-ajax:jar:9.2.22.v20170606:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] \- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO]    \- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The jetty log shows the following

```
3411 [qtp1080615555-20] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel  - HttpChannelOverHttp@31f5a8ff{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=/cometd/test} messageComplete
3411 [qtp1080615555-20] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput  - HttpInputOverHTTP@6f0992d0 EOF
3411 [qtp1080615555-20] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel  - HttpChannelOverHttp@31f5a8ff{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=/cometd/test} handle enter
3412 [qtp1080615555-20 - /cometd/test] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState  - HttpChannelState@738a2171{s=IDLE i=true a=null} handling IDLE
3412 [qtp1080615555-20 - /cometd/test] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel  - HttpChannelOverHttp@31f5a8ff{r=1,c=false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=/cometd/test} action REQUEST_DISPATCH
3412 [qtp1080615555-20 - /cometd/test] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server  - REQUEST GET /cometd/test on HttpChannelOverHttp@31f5a8ff{r=1,c=false,a=DISPATCHED,uri=/cometd/test}
3412 [qtp1080615555-20 - /cometd/test] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  - scope null||/cometd/test @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@35fdf572{/,null,AVAILABLE}
3413 [qtp1080615555-20 - /cometd/test] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler  - context=||/cometd/test @ o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@35fdf572{/,null,AVAILABLE}
3413 [qtp1080615555-20 - /cometd/test] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler  - servlet |/cometd|/test -> org.cometd.server.CometDServlet-629a2d4a@4553b89a==org.cometd.server.CometDServlet,1,true
3413 [qtp1080615555-20 - /cometd/test] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler  - chain=Jetty_WebSocketUpgradeFilter->org.cometd.server.CometDServlet-629a2d4a@4553b89a==org.cometd.server.CometDServlet,1,true
3414 [qtp1080615555-20 - /cometd/test] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler  - call filter Jetty_WebSocketUpgradeFilter
3416 [qtp1080615555-20 - /cometd/test] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler  - call servlet org.cometd.server.CometDServlet-629a2d4a@4553b89a==org.cometd.server.CometDServlet,1,true
3418 [qtp1080615555-20 - /cometd/test] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection  - org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback@62e6f50[PROCESSING][i=ResponseInfo{HTTP/1.1 400 Unknown Bayeux Transport,304,false},cb=org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$CommitCallback@6892f8b1] generate: NEED_HEADER (null,[p=0,l=304,c=2048,r=304],true)@START
```

Where you can see that some Jetty_WebSocketUpgradeFilter is called, which makes me think that the websocket dependency is present but still something goes wrong.

Comment: What server are you deploying your web app to ? I ask because you are using the Jetty specific WebSocket CometD bindings, which require Jetty as a server. Please specify also the exact server version.

Comment: the example in the provided link uses embedded jetty, the version is 9.2.23.v20171218 as noted in the pom's properties

Answer (score 4):

Jetty offers 2 different WebSocket flavors, the standard JSR 356 one and a Jetty specific one.

The first is indicated in Maven artifacts with **javax** in the artifact name, while the second is indicated with **jetty** in the artifact name.

From your POM above you are using `cometd-java-websocket-jetty-server`, which is the CometD binding to the **jetty** WebSocket flavor.

However, you are explicitly specifying as a dependency the `javax-websocket-server-impl` artifact, which is the JSR 356 **javax** flavor.

I am guessing that if you make the dependencies consistent, that is depend on the **javax** flavor only or the **jetty** flavor only will solve your issue.

Unless you need to use the Jetty specific features, I would recommend that you use the JSR 356 **javax** flavor for both the CometD binding (`org.cometd.java:cometd-java-websocket-javax-server`) and the Jetty dependency (`org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-server-impl`).

Comment: I tried using only javax-websocket-server-impl, also adjusted my question showing the mvn dependency:tree. Still no luck though

Comment: You never showed your embedded code, so please make sure that your code resembles what present in [this section](https://docs.cometd.org/current/reference/#_installation_jetty_embedded) of the CometD documentation, in particular the call to `WebSocketServerContainerInitializer` to initialize WebSocket.

Comment: Its the exact code from this [link](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/blob/master/cometd-demo/src/test/java/org/cometd/demo/Demo.java), as mentioned in the question which the section you provided even refers too

Comment: So the code is taken from an actual test and therefore it runs properly. What is different from your configuration and the CometD demo ?

Comment: thats exactly what im trying to find out! I hoped that the dependencies differ in some way and espacially that something websocket related is missing but it seems not, eh?

Comment: If you get the "unknown transport" error, it means that the HTTP request that upgrades to WebSocket is not intercepted by the `WebSocketUpgradeFilter` that is installed by Jetty under the covers (if `WebSocketServerContainerInitializer` is called properly). So two things: 1) call server.dumpStdErr() after you started the server, it should show if the filter is there; 2) take a network dump to see if the WebSocket upgrade request is legit.

Comment: thats what i thought in the first place, but the log says "call filter Jetty_WebSocketUpgradeFilter"

Comment: The log also shows that after the `WebSocketUpgradeFilter` the `CometDServlet` is called, which means that for some reason the WebSocket upgrade was not good, and the filter just forwarded the request. You need to enable the DEBUG level for the `WebSocketUpgradeFilter` to see more about what the filter does, or just debug it.

Comment: I alrady have only one log4j rootLogger which is set to debug and which seems to be used by jetty and cometd. Im not sure if I can get more logging out of it

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue. I tried to track this down. It seems to me that this is caused by the way the bayeux server initializes the websocket transport mappings from the `ws.cometdURLMapping` property. Either that, or I'm using a wrong value of `ws.cometdURLMapping`.

Assuming the websockets dependencies are configured correctly, so using jsr 356, websocket upgrade requests go through Jetty `WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter()`. This method verifies that the request is a legitimate websockets upgrade request and that the one of its mappings matches the websocket request path.

This is where things fail for me. **There is never a successful match**.

I have configured `ws.cometdURLMapping` to `/cometd/*`. I expected this to mean that any websocket request for `/cometd/<whatever/here>` would be accepted.

This is not happening because [AbstractWebSocketTransport.normalizeURLMapping()](https://github.com/cometd/cometd/blob/4.0.3/cometd-java/cometd-java-websocket/cometd-java-websocket-common-server/src/main/java/org/cometd/websocket/server/common/AbstractWebSocketTransport.java#L69-L71) transforms `/cometd/*` into `/cometd` which AFAICS is interpreted by the [Jetty websocket code](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/9b7afd8a0341f4712031abd322ab8669f07f5c5b/jetty-websocket/websocket-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/server/WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java#L227) as a regular expression.
Here's the bit of Comet code I'm referring to:

```
protected List<String> normalizeURLMapping(String urlMapping) {
    String[] mappings = urlMapping.split(",");
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(mappings.length);
    for (String mapping : mappings) {
        if (mapping.endsWith("/*")) {
            mapping = mapping.substring(0, mapping.length() - 2);
        }
        if (!mapping.startsWith("/")) {
            mapping = "/" + mapping;
        }
        result.add(mapping);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The regular expression `^/cometd$` certainly does not match my websocket request path which is `/cometd/`, or `/cometd/something-here`, so the websocket upgrade filter is bypassed.

I haven't tracked down what happens after this, but I assume that since no transport is marked as available, the comet server just bails out with a `HTTP 400 Unknown Bayeux transport`.